# Is there a formula describing the length of line subtended from a chord in a circle? (Picture Included)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Is there a formula that describes the length of line x in a circle, assuming you know the chord length (c), perpendicular distance of the chord from the circumference (d), circle radius (r), and the angle that line x subtends with the chord (a).

[image]

Comment: Try working it out yourself. Note that $c$ is redundant.

Comment: I've been trying but its been throwing my mind in a loop. I know the initial part will somehow be proportional to d/r, since as d goes to r, the value of x will also go towards r, regardless of what angle a is. Beyond that, I cant figure out the exact relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

1. Observe that $MO = r -d$ and since the triangle $AMO$ is right angled, $$AM =\frac{c}{2}= \sqrt{OA^2 - OM^2} = \sqrt{r^2 - (r-d)^2}$$
2. Triangle $MNO$ is right angled and $\angle \, OMN = a$ so 
   $$MN = MO \,\cos(a) = (r-d) \,\cos(a), \,\,\,\, ON = MO \,\sin(a) = (r-d)\, \sin(a)$$
3. Triangle $OND$ is right angled so by Pythagoras' theorem
   $$ND = \sqrt{OD^2 - ON^2} = \sqrt{r^2 -(r-d)^2 \sin^2(a)}$$
4. By the power of point relation
   \begin{align}
    \frac{c^2}{4} &= AM^2 = AM \cdot MB = CM \cdot MD = CM \cdot \Big(MN + ND\Big)\\
   &= x \, \Big( (r-d) \,\cos(a) + \sqrt{r^2 -(r-d)^2 \sin^2(a)}\Big)
   \end{align} thus

$$x = \frac{c^2}{4 \, \Big( (r-d) \,\cos(a) + \sqrt{r^2 -(r-d)^2 \sin^2(a)}\Big)}$$ or equivalently, if you prefer
$$x = \frac{r^2 - (r-d)^2}{(r-d) \,\cos(a) + \sqrt{r^2 -(r-d)^2 \sin^2(a)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

[image: Triangle]

We do not need $c$ to calculate $x$, since $r$ and $d$ determine $c$. Draw a radius to where the line of length $x$ meets the circle. Using the law of cosines we may calculate $x$ as the root of a quadratic equation:
$$r^2=x^2+(r-d)^2-2x(r-d)\cos(\pi-a)$$
$$x^2+(2(r-d)\cos a)x+d^2-2rd=0$$
One root of this equation will always be negative and can be ignored.

Comment: Law of cosines would be more direct wouldn't it?

Comment: @DanielV That only applies with two sides and an _interior_ angle. But this is an exterior angle.

Comment: It relates 3 sides and any angle.  You just solve for the unknown side.

Comment: @DanielV I think I haven't explained my diagram clearer... $r$, $r-d$ and the angle $\pi-a$ are known. $p$, $b$ and $x$ are unknown initially. This is the SSA case (not SAS or SSS, for which the law of cosines would come into play), and thus needs the law of sines.

Comment: I just meant $r^2 = (r - d)^2 + x^2 - 2(r - d)x\cos(\pi - a)$, solve for $x$.

Comment: @DanielV Done, your approach has been adopted.